# What makes the segmentation fault in the short C code?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, compilation

everyone. I wrote the following code, compiled it and ran it but I got a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef long long ll_t;

void store_prod(ll_t * dest, int x, ll_t y) {
    * dest = x * y;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 2049;
    ll_t b = 2147483645;
    ll_t * c;

    store_prod(c, a, b);
    printf("%d * %lld = %lld\n", a, b, *c);

    return 0;
}
```

The debugger in Dev-C++ dumps the following:

```
0x00401500 <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x00401501 <+1>:    mov    %esp, %ebp
0x00401503 <+3>:    push   %ebx
0x00401504 <+4>:    sub    $0xc, %esp
0x00401507 <+7>:    mov    0x10(%ebp), %eax
0x0040150a <+10>:   mov    %eax, -0x10(%ebp)
0x0040150d <+13>:   mov    0x14(%ebp), %eax
0x00401510 <+16>:   mov    %eax, -0xc(%ebp)
0x00401513 <+19>:   mov    0xc(%ebp), %eax
0x00401516 <+22>:   mov    %eax, %edx
0x00401518 <+24>:   sar    $0x1f, %edx
0x0040151b <+27>:   mov    -0x10(%ebp), %ecx
0x0040151e <+30>:   mov    %ecx, %ebx
0x00401520 <+32>:   imul   %edx, %ebx
0x00401523 <+35>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp), %ecx
0x00401526 <+38>:   imul   %eax, %ecx
0x00401529 <+41>:   add    %ebx, %ecx
0x0040152b <+43>:   mull   -0x10(%ebp)
0x0040152e <+46>:   add    %edx, %ecx
0x00401530 <+48>:   mov    %ecx, %edx
0x00401532 <+50>:   mov    0x8(%ebp), %ecx
0x00401535 <+53>:   mov    %eax, (%ecx) ; The problem lies with this line
0x00401537 <+55>:   mov    %edx, 0x4(%ecx)
0x0040153a <+58>:   add    $0xc, %esp
0x0040153d <+61>:   pop    %ebx
0x0040153e <+62>:   pop    %ebp
0x0040153f <+63>:   ret
```

The Register information:

```
EAX 0x7fffe7fd  2147477501
ECX 0x40234e    4203342
EDX 0x400   1024
EBX 0x0 0
ESP 0x63fe58    0x63fe58
EBP 0x63fe68    0x63fe68
ESI 0x3d    61
EDI 0xb70d48    11996488
EIP 0x401535    0x401535 <store_prod+53>
EFLAGS  0x10206 [ PF IF RF ]
CS  0x23    35
SS  0x2b    43
DS  0x2b    43
ES  0x2b    43
FS  0x53    83
GS  0x2b    43
```

There seems to be an overwritten of code at address [%ecx] (i.e., 0x40234e) but why should there be such an access violation? Is anything wrong with the C code?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `ll_t * c;` --> `ll_t d, *c = &d;`

Comment: In `store_prod(c, a, b);`, `c` is uninitialized. Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Yes, the pointer ll_t * c is uninitialized so it could point anywhere. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Can we just appreciate the fact that some one tried running a debugger before posting a question on SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You try to write to memory you don't own → undefined behavior (segfault optional)

In the line `ll_t * c;` `c` is declared, but you use no `malloc` or point it to a valid address (for example: `ll_t d; ll_t *c = &d;`)

change `ll_t * c;` to `ll_t * c = malloc(sizeof(ll_t));` and check if `malloc` failed, or change to `ll_t d; ll_t *c = &d;`

**EDIT:** As @Ajay Brahmakshatriya noted, there is another (chronologically former) undefined behavior - sending that un-initialized variable (`c`) to `store_prod(...)`.

Comment: @fuz how did you make that arrow? (trying to improve my writing :) )

Comment: On Linux with German layout it's AltGr + I. Or with html entities, it's `&rarr;` yielding &rarr; (doesn't work here apparently).

Comment: Before "write to memory you don't own", there is a read on Unintialised value.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya wouldn't that be just reading an intermediate value and not using it, which I think shouldn't be considered ub?

Comment: Reading and passing to a function is technically a use. So yes, it is a UB. Even `{int a; (void)a;}` is UB. In this case, even if `store_prod` doesn't use `dest`, it will UB

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya ok, so basically the fix I provide will account to that as well, but I'll add there are 2 ub. Also, I looked this ub in the C standard and couldn't find - can you kindly provide a source?

Comment: @CIsForCookies [1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p4) states that using an object as argument is an assignment to the parameter. And [2 (point 21)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2p1) says that "use" of uninitialized value is UB. Assignment to another variable counts as a use, since it requires lvalue to rvalue conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding it now

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the crash is undefined behavior when you store a value to the location pointed to by uninitialized pointer `c`.

There is no need to make `c` a pointer, define it as an `ll_t` and pass it's address to the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef long long ll_t;

void store_prod(ll_t *dest, int x, ll_t y) {
    *dest = x * y;
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 2049;
    ll_t b = 2147483645;
    ll_t c;

    store_prod(&c, a, b);
    printf("%d * %lld = %lld\n", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

You could just return the computed value but I suppose the purpose of this code sample is to teach the use of pointers to return computed values.